# Multiline fit-to width UILabel supporting max font size per line and slick animations

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, uilabel, core-text

First time posting here. I am researching how to recreate this super slick text container featured in the Spark Post app from adobe.

IMAGE:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6auPa.png

VIDEO:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfvkreOo3V0&feature=youtu.be

I have already looked into other answers diving into how to calculate the max font size for a container by iterating on different sizes until reaching the better fit.

But if you look carefully this is different:

- The text is being tokenized into words
- The words somehow behave like containers, UIViews perhaps?
- The words animate to it's new position gracefully
- The calculation for max font size occurs in real time!
- Activating the special mode every line expands to it max font size
- It always preservers the given container size

I would love to hear some expert opinions about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can resolve it by following steps

1. Break the text into words.
2. Find the font size of each Word based on rectangle width and height and
   number of character.
3. Create label for each word based on calculating height.

if you do this every time rectangle width height change I think it will look like animation.

Comment: Thanks @JasmeetKaur that reinforces my initial intuition that it seems to be broken into many individual UILabels, one per word. 

What seems non trivial is that kind of "mansory" behavior, specially the way it react when every line expand to its max size. 

All this combined in real-time speed manipulation seems to point to a very valuable algorithm to sort all this so fast... 

Do you think it uses auto-layout or something similar?

Comment: @TonyStark , I don't think AutoLayout is required as you need to create UILabel dynamically one for per word. Every Time RectView Resized You need to start the same algo.

Comment: @TonyStark, Also I have seen there are many option in the example video to change the text, Last one seem to have a label for each word. However other Align Option can be done by single Label.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for helping out.

As described above the trivial part of the solution is to segment the text in words and put it into boxes, for that you can use this:

> -(CGSize)sizeForText:(NSString*)text
>       withHyperLabel:(TTHyperLabel*)hyperLabel{
>
> ```
> CGSize maxSize=CGSizeMake(MAXFLOAT, MAXFLOAT);
>
> NSDictionary *attributes=@{
>                            NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:hyperLabel.fontName size:100],
>
>                            };
>
>
> CGRect textRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:maxSize
>                                      options:0
>                                   attributes:attributes
>                                      context:nil];
>
> return textRect.size; }
> ```

The tricky part is the "sorting" algorihtm. I ended up writing my own "fluid text container" algorithm and it seems to work pretty close to the spark's version
.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yM13PSLW6Fg&feature=youtu.be

The gist is to consider the inner boxes as a fluid being poured into a container. If there's any interest I may open source it later. Let me know!

Thanks!